# How do I save an InfoPath doccument with VBS?

Tags: vbscript, infopath

I am having difficulty performing Save and Close operations in InfoPath through a VBScript.

I'm trying to just perform some simple operations, so I can introduce changes later.  I've checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb229812(v=office.12).aspx) to make sure my syntax is correct...and it seems to be...yet the script crashes during the SAVE and CLOSE operations.

Are there any VBS Guru's out there who can show me what I'm doing wrong?

The logic here is very basic.
1. Provide a list of InfoPath files for me to use.
2. Loop through the file line by line, and perform the open/save/close operation.
3. Quit the program.

Here's the code:

```
'This line gets the current working directory, based off string subtraction from the absolute path of the script - the script's name
workingDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(Len(WScript.ScriptName)))

'We need to provide a name for the file we're going to read.  It's nice to keep this in one place, and not let it change.
Const XMLList = "XML Targets.txt"

'Create a file system object so we can open the list of XML files that you want opened
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'General Error checking, Just making sure there's a XML List file to read from.
If fso.FileExists(workingDirectory & XMLList) Then
    Set targetFile = fso.OpenTextFile(workingDirectory & XMLList)
Else
    MsgBox "You need to have a file called '" & XMLList & "' in the same directory as the script!", 16, "Error"
    WScript.quit()
End If

'Assuming you get this far, you loop through the list file line by line and open/save/close the documents
Do While Not targetFile.AtEndOfStream 
    'Create an InfoPath Application object so we can manipulate our files in InfoPath
    Set InfoPathObject = CreateObject("InfoPath.Application") 
    fileName =  targetFile.ReadLine()   
    Set xdoc = InfoPathObject.XDocuments.Open(fileName+"") 'Open the file (Suggested by Ansgar)
    xdoc.Save 'Save the file (Suggested by Ansgar)
    xdoc.CloseDocument 'Close the file (Suggested by Ansgar)
Loop

MsgBox "Done"
WScript.quit()
```

**Edit: Incorporated accepted answer into script**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XDocuments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb230084) is a collection of [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb230083) objects. It doesn't have a `Save` method, and the parameter of the `Close` method is the index of the object to be closed, not a boolean value. If you want to save and close a particular object, you'll probably have to do it like this:

```
Set xdoc = InfoPathObject.XDocuments.Open(fileName)
xdoc.Save
xdoc.CloseDocument
```

Untested, though, because I don't have a recent enough MS Office at hand.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Ansgar. You were very close with the code, I played with it for about 30 min and finally found that there needs to be some extra quotes concatinated with the fileName argument. I dont know why, but you need those extra quotes. Here's the corrected segment: `Set xdoc = InfoPathObject.XDocuments.Open(fileName + "") xdoc.Save xdoc.CloseDocument`